# css position a text link to the right of a header

Tags: css

What i want to do is have a bold title on the left with a normal size and font text link on the right. The problem can never get only the link beside it. I always get other text or have the link below instead of beside.

test

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="swtitle">
<h1 class="swTitle">Title</h1> <a class="downloadXYZ" href="download.zip">Download</a>
text i dont want. I cant figure out what to write here.
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your CSS that you are using?

Comment: are break-tags that much of a no-no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using the style="display:inline" this will help you get your text you have to wrap around what you are doing, such as images.

```
<h1 class="swTitle" style="display:inline;">Title</h1>
```

You can also use the float if you like too, but inline is much better.

Comment: I'd prefer `inline-block` so you don't loose margin / padding

Answer (score 2):

I am not a CSS guru but you could try the following (note the "display:inline") on the header tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="swtitle">
                <h1 class="swTitle" style="display:inline;">Title</h1> 
                <a class="downloadXYZ" href="download.zip">Download</a>text i dont want. I cant figure out what to write here.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Without providing example CSS that you are using, I would try the following to get your started:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <h1>
                Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <a class="downloadXYZ" href="download.zip">Download</a>text i dont want. I cant
            figure out what to write here.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'without css' ? `float: left` is css. Did you actually try this?

Comment: @Roland, I see why I said that. He didn't provide the CSS (which was asked for), so I said it in such a way of "Without providing us with CSS, try it like this". Updated answer. Thanks for pointing that out